# Transition density of a Geometric Brownian-motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

The solution to SDE
$$dS(t)=\sigma S(t)dW_t$$
is $$S(t)=S(0)\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t)$$
the transition density for this martingale is 
$$p(S(t),t;S(0),0)=\frac{1}{S(t)\sigma \sqrt{2\pi t}}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\log(S_t)-\log(S_0)-\sigma^2 t/2}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}\right]^2\right)}$$
But I can't get this density,here is my proof:

$$\mathbb{P}(S(t)\le u)=\mathbb{P}\left(S(0)\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t+\sigma W_t)\le u\right)$$
$$=\mathbb{P}\left(W_t\le \frac{\log\frac{u}{S(0)}+\sigma^2t/2}{\sigma}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\frac{\log\frac{u}{S(0)}+\sigma^2t/2}{\sigma}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx$$

$$p(S(t),t;S(0),0)=\frac{d}{du}\mathbb{P}(S(t)\le u)=\frac{1}{S(t)\sigma \sqrt{2\pi }}\exp{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\log(S_t)-\log(S_0)+\sigma^2 t/2}{\sigma}\right]^2\right)}$$(take $u=S(t)$)

I got the wrong answer when it comes to $t$.Is there something wrong with my proof?

Comment: **Hint:** $$W_t\sim\mathcal N(0,t)\,.$$ Also, check your lower limit of integration.

Comment: @ki3i Thanks a lot , I have got it!

Comment: You are welcome. One last thought; because you are writing down a pdf, it is convention to use a lower-case letter for the realisation of the random variable, instead of capitals which are usually reserved for the random variable. So, perhaps better to write $$\frac{1}{s_t\sigma\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t}\left( (\log s_t - \log s_0 + \sigma^2t/2)/\sigma \right)^2}$$